# How to capture fleeting bazel console output

Tags: bazel

During a bazel build, there's a bunch of text flying by that's temporarily displayed and then deleted from the screen. This happens all across the build. I've tried a couple of redirection techniques with stderr redirecting to standard output to no avail. I've also experimented with bazel's verbose flags.

**Question**: is there any way to capture this fleeting console output bazel generates? I'd like to at least study what information is being presented before its taken away, more as a learning exercise and to gain familiarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These options should allow you to expand all the log messages generated by actions/tasks and redirect them to a file.

```py
# .bazelrc
common --color=no
common --curses=yes

build --show_progress_rate_limit=0
build --show_task_finish
build --show_timestamps
build --worker_verbose
```

Setting `color=no` and `show_progress_rate_limit=0` results in the progress messages to be *expanded* (and kept) in the terminal.
`curses=yes` affects redirection (at least on my machine). The other flags just add more information to the log.

Example output (bash, bazel 1.0.0)

```
$> bazel build :my_project >& /tmp/bazel_build.log
$> cat /tmp/bazel_build.log

(11:22:46) INFO: Writing tracer profile to '.../command.profile.gz'
(11:22:46) INFO: Current date is 2019-11-01
(11:22:46) Loading: loading...
(11:22:46) Loading: 
(11:22:46) Loading: 0 packages loaded
(11:22:46) Loading: 0 packages loaded
    Fetching @bazel_tools; fetching

(11:22:46) Loading: 0 packages loaded
    Fetching @bazel_tools; fetching

(11:22:46) Loading: 0 packages loaded
    currently loading: path/to/my/project

(11:22:46) Analyzing: target //path/to/my/project:my_project (1 packages l\
oaded)

[...]

(11:22:46) INFO: Analyzed target //path/to/my/project:my_project (14 packages loaded, 670 targets configured).
(11:22:46) 
(11:22:46) INFO: Found 1 target...
(11:22:46) 
(11:22:46) [0 / 1] [Prepa] BazelWorkspaceStatusAction stable-status.txt
(11:22:46) [1 / 13] [Prepa] //path/to/my/project:my_project
(11:22:46) [5 / 12] 3 actions, 0 running
    [Prepa] @deps//:my_dependency

(11:22:46) [10 / 12] [Scann] Compiling path/to/my/project/main.cc
(11:22:46) [10 / 12] [Prepa] Compiling path/to/my/project/main.cc
(11:22:46) [10 / 12] .../project:my_project; 0s processwrapper-sandbox

(11:22:46) [11 / 12] [Prepa] Linking path/to/my/project/my_project
Target //path/to/my/project:my_project up-to-date:
(11:22:46) [12 / 12] checking cached actions
  bazel-bin/path/to/my/project/my_project
(11:22:46) [12 / 12] checking cached actions
(11:22:46) INFO: Elapsed time: 0.493s, Critical Path: 0.29s
(11:22:46) [12 / 12] checking cached actions
(11:22:46) INFO: 2 processes: 2 processwrapper-sandbox.
(11:22:46) [12 / 12] checking cached actions
(11:22:46) INFO: Build completed successfully, 12 total actions
(11:22:46) INFO: Build completed successfully, 12 total actions
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: definitely catching the fleeting stuff now, its interesting to see how the transitions are tracing across time now, I'm seeing things like `Linking...`, and `[-----] //pk1/pk2/pk3:target` --> `[Sched] //pk1/pk2/pk3:target`. There's a ton of empty lines too between status update blocks, 9 newlines delimiting each update. Very worthwhile though to see the Loading phase transition into the Analyzing phase, and then all these actions and their counts and running counts. Definitely too much text to be useful by default, but it was good to write to disk and see this replay once over to study bazel.

Answer (score 3):

```
bazel build //... &> log.txt
```

`&>` does the job

Answer (score 2):

On top of @dms's excellent suggestions, the [`--subcommands` flag](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--subcommands) can be used to persist the exact command line Bazel invokes for each action execution.